# How is FTP metadata copied to the HTTP header?

Tags: ftp, webserver, http, metadata

My understanding is this: In a typical FTP environment with HTTP access, a web server is run on top of the FTP server to provide access to files on the FTP server with HTTP protocol. In the HTTP response header, the `Last-Modified` attribute is the same as the FTP last modified timestamp.

My questions are as follows:

1. Where is the metadata of FTP files (last modified attribute) stored?
2. If FTP metadata is copied into the HTTP response header during a network request, what mechanism is responsible for putting the FTP last modified attribute inside the HTTP response header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The filesystem. Your filesystem keeps track when a file was modified and the FTP and HTTP server just reads that data.
2. None. It's not copied but instead just read from your filesystem as both applications need to read/write the file and would get that information through your operating system anyway.

Comment: Just to clarify: the 'Last-Modified' section of the HTTP response header is taken directly from the FTP server's file system?

Comment: There is no "FTP server filesystem" but rather a general filesystem for that server which might host a FTP server, a HTTP server and a number of other services. All of those would be accessing the same filesystem. If you look for example at the WIkipedia article about [Common filesystem features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_filesystem_features#Dates_handled) you will find a list of common filesystem features. Among them is a "Modified date" which in turn is read by the HTTP server as it delivers the file and by the FTP server as it displays the directory.